# "Resource cannot be found" error when trying to post a submitted form into a ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm relatively new to MVC, I was attempting to create a form in my view page which lets me select data values using a radio button, then pass that data to a controller where it will return it back to the view page with the ViewBag.

This is the model:

```
    public class UserModelR
    {
        public string TeaType { get; set; }
        public string HotelType { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller:

```
    
    
        [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Radio()
            {
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Radio(UserModelR u)
            {
                ViewBag.TeaType = u.TeaType.ToString();
                ViewBag.HotelType = u.HotelType.ToString();
                return View();
            }
```

This is the view:

```
    @model helpers.Models.UserModelR
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Radion", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        Select Tea Type
        

        Tea: @Html.RadioButton("TeaType", "Tea", false)
        | Coffee: @Html.RadioButton("TeaType", "Coffee", true)
        | BlackTea: @Html.RadioButton("TeaType", "BlackTea", false)
        | GreenTea: @Html.RadioButton("TeaType", "GreenTea", false)
        

        Select Hotel Type
        

         Hotel Grand Plaza: @Html.RadioButton("HotelType", "HotelGrandPlaza", false)
        | Hotel Lake View: @Html.RadioButton("HotelType", "HotelLakeView", false)
        | Hotel River Side: @Html.RadioButton("HotelType", "HotelRiverSide", true)
        | Hotel Mountain View: @Html.RadioButton("HotelType", "HotelMountainView", false)
        

        
    }
    
    You Selected
    Tea Type: @ViewBag.TeaType

    Hotel Type: @ViewBag.HotelType
```

When I click submit, it redirects me to "The resource cannot be found." error page.

Comment: In your Html.BeginForm you're posting to an action named Radion, also your return View() form your Get and Post action should be passing a model as a parameter.

Comment: Your Action name(Radio) in the controller doesn't match the View name(Radion) in .cshtml file.